# Delete_by_query in elasticsearch 5.0 using elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to delete a particular document based on Id from the index. While exploring I found that delete_by_query had been deprecated but is now back in versions 5.1 and so on. Can someone please guide me on how and where can I find it in the library. I am using elastic search version 5.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example -

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}]) //your hostname here

es.index(index='your_index_here', doc_type='data', id=id_, body=data_json)

es.delete(index='your_index_here',doc_type='data',id=id_)
```

`pip install elasticsearch` will install the python api in python assuming you have pip.

Comment: This might work. Didn't try. Found an alternate solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that I do not need delete_by_query. It can be done using DocType.
Here is the code:

```
    doc = DocType(Mdm)
    doc.delete(id=1)
```